# jQuery: Slide down navigation bar - how to improve animation smoothness?

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I created a very simple slide-down navigation bar that displays only if the user scrolled down past the main header: http://hammr.co/9525666/23/index.html

However, the animation is staggering and not smooth at all. I suspect it's because it's called all the time while scrolling, but I'm not sure how to just call it once.

My code looks like this:

```
function setOffset() {
    bannerH = $('header').height();
}   

function navTop() {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > bannerH ) {
        $('#navbar').stop().animate({
            top: 0
        }, 100);
    } else {
        $('#navbar').stop().animate({
            top: -61
        }, 100);
    }
}

setOffset();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    navTop();
});
```

If I remove the `.stop()` there's a big delay in the animation (I assume waits enough time to "animate" the bar all the way to the point of scrolling, or it seems that way).

Anyway, my question is simple – how to adjust this so the animation is smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could using cached elements and try by debounce it a little:

```
(function () {  //closure to avoid any global variables
    var timeoutScroll,
        $navbar = $('#navbar'),
        $window = $(window);

    function setOffset() {
        bannerH = $('header').height();
    }

    function navTop() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > bannerH) {
            $navbar.stop().animate({
                top: 0
            }, 100);
        } else {
            $navbar.stop().animate({
                top: -61
            }, 100);
        }
    }

    setOffset();

    $window.scroll(function () {
        clearTimeout(timeoutScroll);
        timeoutScroll = setTimeout(navTop, 35);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, instead of getting the header to drop or hide on every scroll event, you should get the location of the top of the window and the state of the bar, and only change them if necessary:

```
function navTop() {

    var navTopShowing = $('#navbar').css('top') == 0;
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    // If the top of the window is past the banner, and the banner is not showing, show it
    if ((windowTop > bannerH) && (!navTopShowing))
    {
        $('#navbar').stop().animate({
            top: 0
        }, 100);
    }

    // Hide it if it is showing
    if ((windowTop <= bannerH) && (navTopShowing))
    {
        $('#navbar').stop().animate({
            top: -61
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Not tested, but hopefully it gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I also believe it is quite smooth. (at least in my computer)

CSS3 animations should be faster (but I really don't know how much would you notice it in your case). You could try to have a look at something like [CSS with jQuery callbacks](http://addyosmani.com/blog/css3transitions-jquery/).

Or the [jquery.animate-enhanced plugin](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/).